# Flash Builder 4.5 , J2EE plugin

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flash-builder4.5

I need to install the J2EE plugin for my flash builder 4.5 as I am using the blazeDS for my development work. I installed stand alone flash builder 4.5 and java plugin but not able to find any information to install J2EE plugin or Dynamic Web project developement plugin.

Ref: http://blogs.adobe.com/jasonsj/2010/06/java_development_in_flash_builder_4_standalone.html

Please help me if possible.

thanks

Comment: Flash Builder is based on Eclipse which has tons of plugins.  What  plugin specifically are you trying to install?  What problems are you having following the steps in that blog post?

Comment: I was able to install the Java plugin but it wont give me Dynamic Web Project development option. That was just for reference.

Comment: "What" won't give you the Dynamic Web Project development option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to install [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigor) and then install Flash Builder plug-in there [according to instructions](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/890/cpsid_89021.html#main_Install%20your%20software). In reality, it won't create new files in Eclipse folder but creates a link to the Flash Builder installation.